# access pixels in a Mat using OpenCV2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I would like to know **how to access a pixel value and floodfill** it. On the program execution, it finds the white and black pixels, but when applying the floodfill function, the final result is a -all gray- image. What i am trying to do is this:

```
int best_resut = 0;
Point best = (0,0);

for(int i = 0; i < img_bin.rows; i++) 
{
    for(int j = 0; j < img_bin.cols; j++) 
    {  
        Vec3b intensity = img_bin.at<uchar>(i, j);
        uchar color = intensity.val[0];
        printf("Looking (%d,%d) Value %d\n", i, j, color);

        if(color==255)
        {
            printf("White Pixel\n");
            Point sp = (i, j);
            int current_result = floodFill(img_bin, sp, 128);

            if (current_result > best_result)
            {
                best_result = current_result;
                best = Point (i,j);
                floodFill(img_bin,sp, 255);
            }
            else
            {
                floodFill(img_bin, sp, 255);
            }
        }

    }

}

namedWindow("final",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("final", img_bin);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your image is a 3 channel color image

```
    Vec3b intensity = img_bin.at<uchar>(i, j);
```

should be

```
    Vec3b intensity = img_bin.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
```

And since Point takes (x, y) arguments, it should be `Point sp = (j, i);`, not `Point sp = (i, j);`

Correct code:

```
int best_result = 0;
cv::Point best = (0,0);

cv::Vec3b white(255, 255, 255);

for(int i = 0; i < img_bin.rows; i++) 
{
    cv::Vec3b* img_row = img_bin.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < img_bin.cols; j++) 
    {  
        cv::Vec3b pixel = img_row[j];
        printf("Looking (%d,%d) Value %d %d %d\n", j, i, pixel[2], pixel[1], pixel[0]);

        if(pixel == white)
        {
            printf("White Pixel\n");
            cv::Point sp(j, i);
            int current_result = cv::floodFill(img_bin, sp, cv::Scalar(128, 128, 128));

            if (current_result > best_result)
            {
                best_result = current_result;
                best = sp;
            }
            cv::floodFill(img_bin, sp, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));
        }
    }
}

cv::namedWindow("final",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv::imshow("final", img_bin);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Comment: thats right thanks! the problem is that the program blows up when i make this change. Would i need by force to separate the pixel into the 3 channels, in order to read the pixel value?

Comment: What do you mean by "blows up"?
I have corrected your code based on my best guess of what it is supposed to do - and I am really unsure about why you have two flood fills.

Comment: My comment about at argument order was mixed up, removed from my answer.

Comment: i meant that the program exploded but now it's not showing the image, only a white image. But i think i can figure out why. What i want is to create a mask to add to another image afterwards. So now what i need to foodfill any region which doesnt belong to the object located in img_bin, which is a banana. I want only the banana to appear, and the rest --> black

Comment: Can you add your input image to your post, and a clear description (or mock up) of what the output should be. If it's a banana, perhaps you should be searching for yellow, not white.

Comment: I would like to but i need more reputation to add images -.-" but anyway the issue was solved by you. Thanks a lot :D